# Freeze multiple rows in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, freeze

Is it possible to freeze multiple rows at same time (say 1, 25 and 50). i.e. 1<sup>st</sup> row is freeze, when I continue scrolling 25<sup>th</sup> row also freeze below 1<sup>st</sup> row, and continue to scroll ahead from 26<sup>th</sup> row and 50<sup>th</sup> row also freeze below 25<sup>th</sup>. Is it possible using VBA?

Comment: No, Excel doesn't support this.

Comment: Only consecutive rows.

Comment: @Keshab,, Excel does't allows even by using VBA ,, better use SPLIT Window can dived the sheet like crossbar + ☺

Comment: I suggest you vote up the similar requests in the following threads: [Add ability to freeze multiple non-continguous rows. Thanks!](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/38319535-add-ability-to-freeze-multiple-non-continguous-row), [Freeze any/multiple middle rows not next to each other without having to freeze all rows above them](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/35142877-freeze-any-multiple-middle-rows-not-next-to-each-o).

Comment: I agree with Emily's comment of using split screen under the view tab. Hopefully, that helped.

Comment: Thank you all for your response.